# Embed a variable inside an F# quotation

Tags: reflection, f#, quotations

I'm writing an F# dsl for SQL (http://github.com/kolosy/furious).

A select statement would look like this:

```
type person = {
    personId: string
    firstname: string
    lastname: string
    homeAddress: address
    workAddress: address
    altAddresses: address seq
}
and address = {
    addressId: string
    street1: string
    zip: string
}

let (neighbor: person seq) = 
    db.Yield <@ Seq.filter (fun p -> p.homeAddress.zip = '60614') @>
```

The obvious (and silly) question is... How do I parametrize the quotation?

If I just somehting like:

```
let z = "60614"
let (neighbor: person seq) = 
    db.Yield <@ Seq.filter (fun p -> p.homeAddress.zip = z) @>
```

then `z` gets resolved into a static property accessor (`PropertyGet(None, String z, [])`). I need something that will let me retrieve the value of the variable/let binding based solely on the quotation. Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotations are not my forte, but check out the difference here:

```
let z = "60614" 
let foo = <@ List.filter (fun s -> s = z) @> 
printfn "%A" foo

let foo2 = 
    let z = z
    <@ List.filter (fun s -> s = z) @> 
printfn "%A" foo2
```

I think maybe having 'z' be local to the expression means the value is captured, rather than a property reference.

Comment: whoa. neat, thanks. how stable is that going to be? as in, is that an undocumented feature, or just the behaviour of the current iteration? i don't get a lot of warm and fuzzies digging through the quotation stuff.

Comment: I believe it's a stable feature; names declared at the top level are values in a module (properties of a static class), whereas local names are just values.

Comment: d'oh. ok, so it was an issue only because of how my test harness was written. makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Brian wrote - I believe that the encoding of access to global `let` bound values is also pretty stable and they will quite likely continue to be encoded as `PropGet` in the future.

This means that you could support this case explicitly in your translator and add a simple pre-processing step to get values of these properties. This can be done using `ExprShape` (which allows you to fully traverse quotation just using 4 cases). This would allow your DSL to support the general case as well.

The following function traverses quotation and replaces access to global `let`s with their value:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let rec expand e = 
  match e with
  // Extract value of global 'let' bound symbols
  | Patterns.PropertyGet(None, pi, []) -> 
      Expr.Value(pi.GetValue(null, [| |]), e.Type)
  // standard recursive processing of quotations
  | ExprShape.ShapeCombination(a, b) -> 
      ExprShape.RebuildShapeCombination(a, b |> List.map expand)
  | ExprShape.ShapeLambda(v, b) -> Expr.Lambda(v, expand b)
  | ExprShape.ShapeVar(v) -> Expr.Var(v)
```

Then you can write the following to get a quotation that contains value instead of `PropGet`:

```
let z = 5
let eOrig = <@ Seq.filter (fun p -> p = z) [ 1 .. 10 ]@> 
let eNice = expand eOrig
```